# call key press event with AutoComplete option

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I used `KeyPress` Event for changing the focus of the `TextBox`. It works just fine until I use `AutoComplete` option, after this it doesn't work.

Code for `KeyPress`:

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
            txtQuantity.Focus()
            txtQuantity.SelectAll()
            lastTxtBox = "name"
End If
```

Code for `TextBox`:

```
txtProductCode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
txtProductCode.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
```

I want to use both suggestion options. I tried by changing key press to keyDown also but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Use `KeyDown` event instead:

```
Private Sub TB_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtProductCode.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        txtQuantity.Focus()
        txtQuantity.SelectAll()
    End If
End Sub
```

It works perfect for me (tested).